# Javascript string variable unquoted?

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, quickblox

I am using the QuickBlox JavaScript API. Looking through their code, I found this line:

```
var URL_REGEXP = /\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/gi;
```

It appears that it has declared a string variable that is a regular expression pattern. Then it goes ahead to use that variable thus:

```
return str.replace(URL_REGEXP, function(match) {
        url = (/^[a-z]+:/i).test(match) ? match : 'http://' + match;
        url_text = match;
        return '<a href="' + escapeHTML(url) + '" target="_blank">' + escapeHTML(url_text) + '</a>';
    });
```

I am wondering how is this possible? The var declared in the first line should be a string, but it is unquoted. Shouldn't this be a syntax error?

I went ahead and tested this code on my browser, and it works! This mean's I've got some learning to do here... Can anyone explain how this variable is declared?

Additionally, I tried to run the same code on my friends computer, the Chrome debugger throws a syntax error on the variable declaration line (unexpected token '/'). I am using Chrome Version 36.0.1985.143 m, my friend is using the same thing, but on my computer, it all works fine, on my friends computer, the code stops at the first variable declaration because of "syntax error".

Is there some setting that is different?

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the quick answers. I've come from a PHP background, so thought that all regular expressions has to be initialized as strings :P.

Anyone can reproduce the syntax error I'm getting on my friends computer? (It still happens after disabling all extensions). I can't reproduce it either, and that's what is frustrating me.

**UPDATE 2**

I have tested and my friends computer and looked through the source. It appear to be due to some encoding problems (I'm not sure what). The regular expression is shown like this:

```
var URL_REGEXP = /\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?芦禄鈥溾€濃€樷€橾))/gi;
```

(The characters at the end of the code is some random chinese characters, it seems).

How can I change the encoding to match his browser/system? (He is running on a Windows 7 Chinese simplified system).

Comment: Regular expressions are not strings.

Comment: I can't reproduce the syntax error, either. You must have made a mistake when copying it on your friend's computer.

Comment: Hmm.. I have uploaded it to a webserver, it is accessible through a url which you type in your browser, so the files should be exactly the same, right?

Comment: Try disabling all Chrome extensions on his computer.

Comment: Do you mean that `var URL_REGEXP = /\b((?:https.......` **should** be a syntax error? [No, regex is special. Read this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Is there a possibility some browsers does not support this type of declaration? my friends Chrome throws the syntax error I was expecting at that line (unexpected token /).

Comment: All browsers understand this, and have for years and years and years.

Comment: Does it also happen on his computer if he pastes the declaration into the Javascript console, like I did?

Comment: @Unihedron: i think that is declared earlier in the SDK. The error was only at the first line.

Comment: @Barmar: Urgh.. my friend has to log off so I can't test if it works by pasting it into the console. (I will at the first opportunity and post back with the results tomorrow)

Answer (score 2):

It is not a String variable. It is a **regular expression**.

Calling `var varname = /pattern/flags;`
is effective to calling `var varname = new RegExp("pattern", "flags");`.

You can execute the following in any browser that supports a JavaScript console:

```
>>> var regex = /(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+/i
>>> regex.exec("google.com")
... ["google.com"]
>>> regex.exec("www.google.com")
... ["www.google.com"]
>>> regex.exec("ftp://ftp.google.com")
... ["ftp.google.com"]
>>> regex.exec("http://www.google.com")
```

---

> Anyone can reproduce the syntax error I'm getting on my friends computer? (It still happens after disabling all extensions). I can't reproduce it either, and that's what is frustrating me.

According to [RegExp - JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

Regex literals was present in ECMAScript 1st Edition, implemented in JavaScript 1.1. Use an updated browser.

Comment: **"Use an updated browser."** How old *does* your browser need to be? ;)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I have no idea. Supposedly, Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera and Safari has support. Without more information, [the straightforward assumption](http://www.xkcd.com/1339/) would be if the browser is very, very outdated.

Comment: I'd guess that the OP has done something weird. As far as I'm aware, all JavaScript implementations support this, even IE5 and below.

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't be a syntax error. In Javascript, `RegExp` objects are not strings, they are a distinct class of objects. `/.../modifiers` is the syntax for a `RegExp` literal.

I can't explain the syntax error you got on your friend's computer, it looks fine to me. I pasted it into the Javascript console and it was fine.

Comment: Is it a distinct datatype or just a class?

Comment: @Rudie `typeof /.*/` returns `"object"`, so it's just a class, with a built in literal.